# Max Usable Memory - Windows 7 Pro 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, memory

Specs beforehand (Upgraded HP m8530f): AMD Phenom X4 9550 @ 2.20 GHz / HIS 256MB Radeon HD4350 GDDR2 PCI-E / 6.0 GB PC2-6400 DDR2 RAM / 750GB SATA Seagate Barracuda HDD / ASUS M2N78-LA / CoolerMaster 500W PSU

So, this computer comes stock with 5.0 GB of RAM. So in the four slots, there is a 1 GB - 1 GB - 2 GB - 1 GB configuration. Today, though, I got another 2GB stick, so now I have a configuration of 1 GB - 1 GB - 2 GB - 2 GB. However, after I booted up... I went to Computer Properties and it says that I only have 5.0 GB Usable memory. However, I checked online and for Windows 7 Pro 64-bit, the max supported memory should be much much more.

Any ideas? Are there questions like this already? (oops)

EDIT1: for Sim...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you upgraded the BIOS? There is a BIOS update for your model ([HP m8530f](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3740333&)) on the HP website that might do the trick [M2N78-LA Motherboard BIOS update improves security support, and fixes incorrect memory size being reported in Vista when 4GB or more is installed](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-73127-1&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&os=2100&product=3740333).

There is a good page on the HP Site that walks you through [upgrading to Windows 7](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01778879&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3740333) and covers know issues and solutions etc.

Comment: I flashed the BIOS when it had Vista 64-bit... would I still need to do it now?

Comment: Well I guess that depends on which BIOS version you used. The one in the link is from July last year and is version 5.29. Which one did you install?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if I installed that one then... but the only one available on the site is for Vista 64-bit, and it won't install on my 7 64-bit...

Comment: If you run "System Information" then the system summary will tell you which BIOS version you are using.

Try installing it with the "Run as Administrator" option and set compatibility to be Vista.

Comment: Wesley, Did you work out which BIOS version you had installed?

Comment: Yeah, my BIOS version is out of date, but HP doesn't have an official download for Windows 7 64-bit to flash the BIOS.

Comment: Ok, as Windows 7 is very very similar to Vista have you tried my suggestion of changing the compatibility mode for the BIOS update? I have used that to successfully to get around similar issues where updates detect the OS version and won't run.  

To do this just right click on the update and select Properties and then the Compatibility tab and Choose Vista as the operating System.

Comment: Still won't work... even when running as administrator... because the download file that I open shows the download info (click Next) and then extracts the installer... but the installer has System Requirements as well... so unless I could change the compatibility of that installer (which I don't know how to do), then it would work...

Comment: HP aren't trying to make this easy. Instead of running the update file try to open it With 7Zip (or similar Zip archive opening program) and extract all the files to a folder. In the folder you will find an exe called AFUWIN.exe, change the compatibility setting for that and run it and see if that works.

Comment: The download is an .exe itself. Is it possible to extract a .exe from a .exe??

Comment: It is a self-extracting zip file - basically a zip encapsulated in an exe that extracts the files and then executes the contents. These can be cracked open with WinZip or 7zip etc so you can have your way with the contents. So when you have got a zip reader installed right-click on the exe and choose open zip/archive and you should be able to save the contents to a separate folder.

Comment: Okay... I have extracted the files from the .exe, but there are no relevant files in there... no more .exe files.

Comment: That is weird. The exe is sp43100.exe and should contain the following eight files AFUWIN.exe, cPC_DMIRD.dll, Installer.exe, sp43100.rtf, Ucoresys.sys, Ucorevxd.vxd, Ucorew64.sys and VIO5.29. If you just open the archive in 7zip then all that will appear as a folder with no name, if you double-click on that it will open the folder and all the files should be there.

Comment: I will edit later with a screen shot of the files extracted. I used 7zip by the way...

Comment: If it makes it easier for you I have uploaded a zip version of the contents of the exe to http://rapidshare.com/files/348452785/sp43100.zip.html. For your own peace of mind please scan it for viruses etc before opening.

Comment: That doesn't look right, it looks like you have opened it but not as a ZIP archive. Try downloading it again and then right-click on it and choose "Open Archive" or "Extract to 43100\"from the 7-Zip sub-menu.

Comment: The screenshot was from my downloaded sp43100.exe. However, even trying to run AFUWIN.exe or Installer.exe with Vista compatibility & running as administrator still does not work. It will just show a dialog box before the BIOS Update saying that my computer doesn't meet minimum reqs.

Comment: The only think I can think of now trying is booting your PC from a Vista install DVD and exiting to the Command Prompt (http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/tutorial147.html) and running the update from there.

Comment: You could also try contacting HP Support or use the HP Support Forums (http://h30434.www3.hp.com/ ) ?

Comment: Or better still ask another question here at SuperUser about how to update your BIOS. ;)

Comment: Haha, well I think it's more a compatibility issue, than a BIOS updating issue. You can't manually update a BIOS, because you need official software to do it. Still, I may end up calling HP... we'll see.

Comment: When you ran the individual files, did you extract them or just open the archive and run them? It may be worth extracting them to a directory - setting the compatibility etc and then running them again if you didn't. You could also use the right-click "Troubleshoot Compatibility" option which walks you through trying to get around problems like this.

Comment: One last try, Have a read of the last post by sumsolstice at http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Operating-systems-and-software/Bios-driver-updates-for-Windows-7/m-p/175142/highlight/true. Follow his instructions but substitute VIO5.29 where he has BEN5.32. An alternative approach is at http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Hardware/m9400t-BIOS-does-not-update/m-p/7127 - the post by monsieurglad at the end of the first page.

Comment: Hmph... that seems only to work for a version 5.32 upgrade on a different BIOS. But will definitely try it once I get home. Thanks for all your help! =P

Comment: Yes it it is a different BIOS and version but it uses the same BIOS updating software AFUWIN.exe. Have you actually gone into the BIOS and seen what that is reporting rather than just using Speccy and CPU-Z?

Comment: BIOS reads all the memory. Shows each slot AND the total (6144MB).

Comment: Good to hear. I still think that the BIOS update will fix the problem - though that is going to be tricky to install as you have found.

Comment: Yep. It will... and thing is, I don't wanna revert to Vista 64-bit or try to get Vista 64-bit and 7 64-bit to dual boot because this is a family computer and my parents don't like me messing around with computers. hehe.

If only there was a simple, direct way to get this done.

Comment: As a last resort I'd contact HP and ask them for a Windows 7 compatible BIOS. Try http://twitter.com/HPSupport and http://twitter.com/HP_Listens

Comment: AH thanks Sim! They're processing the request now... will update when I get a solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: No worries, I hope it works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the memory is correctly detected in the BIOS, run **MSCONFIG**, open the **Boot** tab, click **Advanced Options**, make sure that **Maximum Memory** is not capped.

[image]

Comment: There is no cap on the max memory. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Wesley - check the box and use 6144 as max

Comment: Setting the cap doesn't change anything... it still says 5.0 GB usable.

Comment: @Wesley - memory modules are identical in terms of specifications? tested with memtest86+?

Comment: One of them is slightly different from the rest, but they are all PC2-6400 DDR2 RAM... would that be a problem?

Comment: I did Memtest86+ on all my computers and all passed with no errors... may be the BIOS... as Sim is saying.

Answer (score 0):

What does your BIOS says? That's what I would look first. If BIOS says 6 you know the problem is with windows and vice-versa.

Another very useful thing to do is run [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/cpuz.php). Cpu-z will not merely tell you how much RAM you have, it's gonna tell you how much ram is installed **per slot**. Chances are the slot order will match your motherboard order, you just have to figure which one is first. If one of the slot shows empty, try to remove that RAM and go back in cpu-z to confirm you removed the right one. Mark it.

Then try to remove all RAM except the 'faulty' one and try it alone - can you boot? If no, try a different slot, but it may be bad ram. If you can boot, it means your motherboard is just having a hard time with dealing with the 4 at once (different models, etc.). You can help it by reordering the slots, slacking the timings, reduce memory speed a little, etc from your BIOS.

I am running 8gb here and windows 7 sure detects them all.

Comment: I'm using Speccy and it recognizes them all.

Comment: CPU-Z also recognizes them all